# Can't run dynos

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

After deploying my django-site to heroku(finally!) i've got "error code H14". Then i tried to scaling dynos but the following error occurred:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... !
▸    Couldn't find that process type.
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn Django_work.wsgi
```

Project link:
https://github.com/AlfredMulder/Django_work

Full logs:

```
2018-03-22T18:08:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user xanderhref@protonmail.com

2018-03-22T18:08:50.392177+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-curved-78959) by user xanderhref@protonmail.com

2018-03-22T18:08:50.392177+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user xanderhref@protonmail.com

2018-03-22T18:08:50.658643+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user xanderhref@protonmail.com

2018-03-22T18:08:50.658643+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 11510f4e by user xanderhref@protonmail.com

2018-03-22T18:08:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2018-03-22T18:08:57.301783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-wildwood-73678.herokuapp.com request_id=b3bbcf39-a609-4568-b7f1-d6e83c877b48 fwd="178.64.164.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-22T18:08:59.619356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-wildwood-73678.herokuapp.com request_id=31d8fc72-120b-4006-ae41-c8b95a99357f fwd="178.64.164.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-22T18:08:59.792765+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-wildwood-73678.herokuapp.com request_id=0add7b9c-0f00-4514-8ca5-7c2e353b4773 fwd="178.64.164.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-22T18:09:50.176125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-wildwood-73678.herokuapp.com request_id=b9ffc587-ffda-4b82-85c0-22032f288b3f fwd="178.64.164.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Both error code H14 and that message are telling you that it can't find the web process. So for some reason it is not recognizing your Procfile. Please post your project file layout and the full logs.

Comment: I added project link and full logs. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case is important. The file must be called `Procfile`, not `procfile`.

Comment: That's great, but i still getting same problem. Even adding ":application --log-file-" don't helps much.

Comment: Forget about my previous words. I pushed project again and deal with that problems. But another one happend.